# Why does Throwable catch ignore 'continue' but it does work with 'return'?

Tags: php, try-catch, throwable

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($inDomainLinks as $href) {
    try {
        $page->goto($href, ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle2']);
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

I would like that if the code inside Try fails, we continue to the next value in the loop.

However, the code above throws the error anyway and the execution ends.

If I try to do this for instance:

```
foreach ($inDomainLinks as $href) {
    try {
        $page->goto($href, ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle2']);
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        return $href.' fails';
    }
}
```

It actually returns that value, so I'm actually reaching the catch, but I just don't know why the first code doesn't execute as intended (by me).

Any ideas?

So far my **workaround** is creating a private function that wraps the try catch:

```
foreach ($inDomainLinks as $href) 
    $this->analyzePage($page,$href);

private function analyzePage($page,$href){
    try {
        $page->goto($href, ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle2']);
        return true;
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context. [The loop should keep iterating just fine.](https://3v4l.org/QiDBR) Note that `continue` serves no purpose in this case though, you're basically just muting the exception.

Comment: I added `continue` as if I leave the catch empty, it throws the exception and doesn't catch it. I had to include a helper function to handle it, which works. Not sure why the try catch is forcing me to include a return statement

Answer (score 0):

If it throws the error then you are not catching the correct error. The continue will work there, and to be honest it is redundant since the code will go anyway.

Comment: If I remove the continue, it also throws the error and finish the code - the catch is only working if I put a return inside

Comment: Can you post the error and error type because I think you are catching wrong error.

Comment: `\Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command "node C:\xampp\htdocs\gdpr\node_modules\@nesk\rialto\src\node-process\serve.js C:\xampp\htdocs\gdpr\vendor\nesk\puphpeteer\src\PuppeteerConnectionDelegate.js "{""idle_timeout"":60,""log_node_console"":false,""log_browser_console"":false}"" failed.`

Throwable should handle everything, shouldn't it?

Comment: Can you try and put **Exception** instead of **Throwable**

Comment: I did, same thing - I solved it by including the try catch in a different private function that returns true or false, but I'm still a bit confused about why I can't simply catch the issue and do nothing (let the code continue)

Comment: It should not be. This is precisely why try catch is used. Nonetheless congratz on the fix.